# measure columns in tabular model not displaying correct values in browser

Tags: t-sql, ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

i have problem with tabular model where i often get same(max) values when browsing model by different categories.
for example if i try to browse paymentType table with  measure columns from payment table  measure columns  have ok results, but if i try to browse rooms table with  measure columns from payment table  measure columns  have same(sum of all) results.
I guess mistake is in the relation between payment table and renting table but i don't know how to fix it.
code in tabular model is not in english so i tried to translate the best i could.
thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIerO.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could change your definition of [UkupanIznosBezPopusta] to be as follows:

Pre-SSAS2016:

```
UkupanIznosBezPopusta =
CALCULATE (
  <pre-existing measure logic>,
  'iznajmljivanje'
)
```

SSAS2016 and later:

```
CALCULATE (
  <pre-existing measure logic>,
  CROSSFILTER ( 'iznajmljivanje'[uplataID], 'uplata'[uplataID], BOTH ) // I'm guessing on the key
                                                                       // column here. These are
                                                                       // the same name in both.
```

These are the general patterns for filtering from a many table to a 1 table, which is what you need to do here. In SSAS2016 and later, there is also the possibility to make the relationship between the two tables a bidirectional relationship, but I don't typically recommend this as the first thing to try.

Comment: Thanks for response! I am not very familiar with interface so i don't know how to change definition of column, so if you can guide me i would really appreciate it

Comment: Those are not columns, but measures. I suggest working through a tutorial for SSAS Tabular, this is well beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question. [Here is a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-modeling-adventure-works-tutorial?view=sql-server-2014)